# More than one value in Smarty {if}

Tags: php, smarty, if-statement

Hy i have this code.

```
{if $isModerator && $order->kind==1}
bla bla
{/if}
```

and $order->kind can be 1,2,3,4,6 
so making 5 if is not the idea any idea?

Comment: You're question is a bit confusing, exactly what do you want to know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't this work for you?

```
{if $isModerator && in_array($order->kind, array(1,2,3,4,5))}
bla bla
{/if}
```

Haven't used Smarty for quite a while now, so not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Smarty has a for or while cycle? You could always cycle on that like in pseudocode here:

```
for($i=0;$i>max($order->kind);$i++){
  if($isModerator and $order->kind==$i){
    //code here
  }
}
```